# RDLC Report > Chart > How to display column name/title/label (x axis) vertically?

Tags: asp.net, report, rdlc

In Column chart of `RDLC report`, how to set `x-axis label (titles) vertically`?

If the x axis names/titles are bigger then 2nd columns title goes in next line... i want all columns titles displayed vertically.

Answer (score 1):

In Column chart of RDLC report, to set x-axis label (titles) vertically, follow the below steps

1. Right click on X-axis  and select Axis Properties,
2. It will open window with different tabs like Axis Options, Labels, Label font...
3. Select Labels--> Set axis Label Options
4. Select Radio button Disable auto fit and set label rotation angle 90.
   it will show the labels vertically in the x-axis...

Hope it will help for ur query.

-Divakar

Answer (score 0):

set writing mode to "tb-rl" and check TextAlign and VerticalAlign to make sure it looks like you want it to

Answer (score 0):

If text-align doesn't work, you can use report->properties, use the code tab, and write a function with input text that outputs vertical text as an image. Code for that you can find via Google.

Answer (score 0):

Set the label Rotation Angle to 90.

Comment: Can you pls let me know the steps to do it?